# First Row Always Gets Selected When Focussing a TableView or TreeView in a JavaFX Application

Tags: user-interface, select, javafx, treeview, tableview

I realised that all tableViews and treeViews in my JavaFX application are selecting the first row as soon as they get focused. As a result even when I click on a corresponding scrollbar, the first row will be selected. Since I of course do not want to have such a behaviour, I would like to to ask, if there is a way to avoid this behaviour?

EDIT: I added a simple example that creats two humble lists. Here as soon as one clicks on an empty row, the first row gets selected.

EDIT 2: Added two small listener to the code, so that the problem is repeatable without restarting the application.

```
package testlistview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestListView extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);

        Scene primaryStageScene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryStageScene);

        ListView<String> l1 = new ListView();
        l1.getItems().addAll("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
        ListView<String> l2 = new ListView();
        l2.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
        root.getChildren().addAll(l1, l2);

        l1.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            l2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        });

        l2.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            l1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

EDIT 3: I realised that the first row also gets selected, when I am sorting a table. However, to avoid this, I created a little hack (which is probably a very bad style, but it works for now).

```
  private boolean sorted = false;

// (...)

    tableView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                                    if (!tableView.isFocused()) {
                                        if (e.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode() instanceof Label) {
                                            sorted = true;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            ;
                    });

    tableView.focusedProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
                if(!tableView.isPressed() || sorted) {
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    sorted = false;
                }
            });
```

So here the eventFilter is activated before the listener. As far as I can see, only the header is of instance Label. As a result each time the header is clicked first, the selection gets cleared.

However, as discussed in the post below, I guess, the bug will disappear with the next java release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` for clearing the selected row. Because you want to remove it when your table is getting focused, just put it inside Listener of the `focusedProperty` of the table.

```
 table.focusedProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
        ...
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
 });
```

Edit for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576575/first-row-always-gets-selected-when-focussing-a-tableview-or-treeview-in-a-javaf/27577730?noredirect=1#comment43602945_27577730)

I am not sure what you are trying to do with a `ListView`, when your question talks about `TableView` and `TreeView`.

You should use the same listener in for your `ListView`

```
l1.focusedProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
    if(!l1.isPressed()) {
        l1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

**Note** : This will lead to not able to not able to select the rows with one click

**Update** : **Complete Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestListView extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);

        Scene primaryStageScene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryStageScene);

        ListView<String> l1 = new ListView();
        l1.getItems().addAll("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
        ListView<String> l2 = new ListView();
        l2.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
        root.getChildren().addAll(l1, l2);

        l1.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            l2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        });

        l2.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            l1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        });

        l1.focusedProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
            if(!l1.isPressed()) {
                l1.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the problem with this approach is that the listener also gets fired when I explicitly click on a row. In such a case the row should be selected. Sorry for not pointing this out correctly. So is there also a way to avoid the listener to fire, when I explicitly click on a non-empty row?

Comment: The table never selects a row on the first mouse click. The first mouse click is reserved for focus. From second click onwards, table will listen to row selection.

Comment: Thanks for being so interested in my problem. However, I added a code snippet in my initial post. So when you start this code and click on an empty row, the first row is always selected in the application, which for me is an unintuitive behaviour.

Comment: You could replace the ListView with a TableView. The behaviour would be exactly the same. As I already said: The listener you are adding is indeed avoiding a row/entry selection. However, when I click on a row/entry that is non-empty, I would like to select the row with just one click. Unfortunately this is not the case in your solution.

Comment: Are you just concerned about mouse clicks?

Comment: I generally would like to select a row also by using arrow keys of the keyboard. However, I think focussing a table is currently only possible, when clicking on it. So when the corresponding table is not focused, it is sufficient, if only clicks on a non-empty row would be accepted. As soon a row is selected, it should also be possible to use the arrow keys for selecting a new row.

Comment: It is is just for MouseClicks, you can overcome this by checking if the event has been fired because of the Mouse Press or not and just skip it. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Although the first row still gets selected, when clicking on it, this avoids the first row from getting selected, when I click on the corresponding scrollbar, which was the most annoying behaviour. Do you know if it is somehow possible to check, whether a certain row of a list/table is pressed? I think this could solve my problem completely.

Comment: I do not understand your issue. Does the first row still gets selected when the application starts?

Comment: The problem is not just that the first row gets selected when the application starts, but also when I click an empty row. So if a row has three entries and I click below the third entry, the first row gets selected. However, the first row should only be selected, when I directly click on the first row.

Comment: I don't have any such issues, please check the complete code I just added, for reference.

Comment: I checked it and the same bug appears. Obiously you did not get my problem yet. So I created a small video that shows what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0ejG-ss1to&feature=youtu.be . So when I click below the last row entry, the first row always gets selected, which I do not want to have. Thanks once more for spending so much time with my problem.

Comment: None of this can be reproduced on my system. Using Java 8 on OSX.

Comment: That's... interesting. I know tried out the early acces release java 1.8.0_U40 b19, and that behaviour vanished. Are you using th same build? Anyway, I 

guess the problem will be solved with the next java update and for now your suggestion plus the little hack I did by myself will make this bug bearable. => SOLVED (Thanks, merry Christmas and a happy new year!)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Found this answer very helpful:

[How to make the first 2 rows in a JavaFX listview non-selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521658/how-to-make-the-first-2-rows-in-a-javafx-listview-non-selectable)

> Depending on which exact (update) version of jdk8 you are using, this might be the fix for RT-25679 (partially reverted in RT-38517) AFAIK, there is no public api to disable the auto-focus/select for the collection views in general. Only ListView has (undocumented! beware, they can change without notice) entries in its properties that disable the default behaviour

```
// disable selecting the first item on focus gain - this is
// not what is expected in the ComboBox control (unlike the
// ListView control, which does this).
listView.getProperties().put("selectOnFocusGain", false);
// introduced between 8u20 and 8u40b7
// with this, testfailures back to normal
listView.getProperties().put("selectFirstRowByDefault", false);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I tried it out with my test program and it worked for ListViews! Unfortunately it did not solve the problem for TableViews. Nevertheless, with the current version 1.8.0_40 this problem does not appear anymore, so that this fix is not necessary anymore (even for tables). If possible, you can try the current JDK version with your program and let me know if it also fixes your problem.