# Why my TableView first row is selected?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I've created a TableView in JavaFx. Everything works fine except that for some reason the table first row is automatically selected and I don't want this to happen.

My fxml file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" id="rootPane"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <TableView fx:id="myTable">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="column1" maxWidth="5000.0"
                minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="column1" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="column2" maxWidth="5000.0"
                minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="column2" />

        </columns>
    </TableView>
</fx:root>
```

My data controller:

```
public class TableController extends AnchorPane{

    @FXML private TableView<DataClass> myTable;
    @FXML private TableColumn<DataClass, String> column1;
    @FXML private TableColumn<DataClass, Integer> column2;

    public TableController(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "/fxml/Temp.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
            initComponents();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        column1.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<DataClass, String>("column1"));
        column2.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<DataClass, Integer>("column2"));

            ArrayList<DataClass> list = new ArrayList<DataClass>();
            list.add(new DataClass("S1", 1));
            list.add(new DataClass("S2", 2));
            list.add(new DataClass("S3", 3));

            ObservableList<DataClass> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
            myTable.setItems(data);

    }
}
```

DataClass:

```
public class DataClass{
        private StringProperty column1;
        private IntegerProperty column2;

        private DataClass(String column1, int column2){
            this.column1 = new SimpleStringProperty(column1);
            this.column2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(column2);
        }

        public String getColumn1() {
            return column1.get();
        }
        public void setColumn1(String column1) {
            this.column1.set(column1);
        }
        public int getColumn2() {
            return column2.get();
        }
        public void setColumn2(int column) {
            this.column2.set(column);
        }

    }
```

Can you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: And there is no more code regarding the `TableView`? I can not reproduce this behavior..

Comment: @eckig I don't think so. Nevertheless I've updated my question with all the code being used.

Comment: `@FXML private TableColumn<DataClass, Integer> column1;` - Shouldn't this be `column2`?

Comment: @hfontanez Yes and it is column2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour of JavaFX TableView. You need to clear the selection of the table, by using `table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();`

This usually happens because the table gets focus on it. The final code that you are looking for is

```
peopleTable.focusedProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> {
    peopleTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
});
```

**For more information :**

[First Row Always Gets Selected When Focussing a TableView or TreeView in a JavaFX Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576575/first-row-always-gets-selected-when-focussing-a-tableview-or-treeview-in-a-javaf)